# PHP и Imagick. Как правильно установить?

Tags: php, centos, imagemagick, pecl

Хочу установить Imagick в CentOS. Соответственно буду использовать данную либу из PHP.
Находил разные способы установки модуля в PHP. Это и через yum и через pecl install...
Собственно вопрос, в чём вообще будет разница установки через менеджер YUM и через PECL? Просто я всю жизнь устанавливал через yum install php-* , а тут pecl.. Никогда с ним не работал даже. Могу ли я без сомнений ставить через "yum install php-pecl-imagick"? Если поставлю через PECL, в чём будет разница?

Comment: PECL - это механизм сборки расширений из исходных кодов PHP. YUM - это менеджер пакетов в CentOS. Не понятно что вы хотите получить и где?

Comment: Есть ли какая-то разница, ставить из PECL или через YUM?

Comment: Ну это разные механизмы. Например, в Windows YUM работать не будет, а PECL наверное будет.

Comment: Какая версия CentOS? YUM как бы немного устарел. Вместо него уже лет 6 как используют DNF

Comment: сам [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/) работает хорошо и без php. А из php его можно использовать без модуля. Для CentOS можно взять тут https://urban-warrior.org/ImageMagick/download/linux/CentOS/x86_64/